# Does someone know an online-applet for the Risch-algorithm?

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request, algorithms, math-software

The Risch-algorithm allows to determine whether a given function has an elementary antiderivate (and to calculate it, when it exists).

> Does someone know an online-applet for this algorithm ?

I have heard that some math-programs support the Risch-algorithm, but I could not find an online-applet. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha implements the Risch algorithm, and has a web interface.

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)

Comment: I know the Wolfram applet, but isn't the calculation time limited ?

Comment: You may pay $7/month to remove the limitation. But even with the limitation, I haven't seen anything with web interface and free which would be even remotely as good.

Comment: Maybe try [Sage](https://cloud.sagemath.com)

Comment: Would "Sage" be free ? And how large is the main-file ?

Comment: You have to understand that "free" means "limited" in order to convince you to pay for an "upgrade". In other words nobody will pay the bill so you can run for free your computationally intensive job. If you have a good computer and you need something on short term, I recommend you to download and install Matematica 15-days free trial on your own computer. Or Maple.

Answer (score 0):

You can download [FriCAS](http://fricas-wiki.math.uni.wroc.pl) and [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) for free. Both have an online applet.

FriCAS has the most comprehensive implementation of the Risch algorithm.

The name of the FriCAS online applet is [FriCAS Sandbox](http://axiom-wiki.newsynthesis.org/FriCASIntegration).

Type there into the box at the end of the website:
\begin {axiom}
integrate(exp(x-x^2),x)
\end {axiom}

Press the Preview button then.

see also:

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/)

The Risch algorithm part of the integration algorithms is only for the [Elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).